# VB.Net - My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile() Won't Let Me Copy a File to a Directory

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Basically I'm writing a program what will allow the user to choose a file or directory to copy over a network based on a set of stations and then they type in the location to copy those file/directory to.

I'm getting close to finishing I think but I'm having an issue with the My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile() method. I'm checking beforehand to see if the user-selected item to copy is a file or directory but in the case that the user enters a directory for the file to be copied to I get an error telling me that "The given file path ends with a directory separator character.", even though it's the DESTINATION location that it's erroring out on. I need to be able to have it copy a file to a directory if a directory is specified without a filename.

I tried playing around with the Trim functions and copying the name to the end of the destination path but I'm having a hard time getting just the file name of the source file.

Any ideas?

Here's the code for my fileCopy function far-

```
        If (pushFileSelectCheckBox1.Enabled) Then
        For Each item As String In stations
            copyTo = Path.Combine(copyTo, stations([i].ToString))
            copyToLoc = copyTo.ToString
            copyToLoc = Path.Combine(copyTo, pushLocationBox1.ToString.Remove(0, 36))

            If Directory.Exists(pushFrom1) Then
                If (System.IO.Directory.Exists(copyToLoc)) Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(pushFrom1, copyToLoc, True)
                    LogOutput("Directory 1 copied.")
                Else
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(copyToLoc)
                    LogOutput("Directory created.")
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(pushFrom1, copyToLoc, True)
                    LogOutput("Directory 1 copied.")
                End If
            ElseIf File.Exists(pushFrom1) Then
                If (System.IO.Directory.Exists(copyToLoc)) Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(pushFrom1, copyToLoc, True)
                    LogOutput("File 1 copied.")
                Else
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(copyToLoc)
                    LogOutput("Directory created.")
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(pushFrom1, copyToLoc, True)
                    LogOutput("File 1 copied.")
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox("Chosen file, or whatever, is neither a file nor a directory. What did you do?!?!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Umm....")
            End If
            i += 1
        Next
        i = 0
    End If
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Path.GetFileName to get the filename from the pushFrom and append it at the end of copyToLoc. I'm pretty sure the "to" has to contain the filename, not just the folder.

Comment: `FileCopy` requires sourceFileName and destfilename, not just folder names

Comment: use debug.writeline to see what data you are actually sending to the CopyFile method

Comment: @the_lotus Perfect! That's EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you! If you wanna put that in as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the filename from the pushFrom variable and append it at the end of copyToLoc. The second parameter of [CopyFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127963(v=vs.110).aspx) need to end with a filename, not just a path.